# Make specific products accessible only to a user role in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am making a plugin to hide specific product category only for a user role.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'wcpp_hide_product' );
function wcpp_hide_product( $q ) {
    //if main query, skip
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    //jika admin, skip
    if(is_admin()) return;
    //if user is not logged in, or dont have PRIVATE_MEMBER roles hide the product
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!isset($current_user->roles) || !in_array('PRIVATE_MEMBER', $current_user->roles)){ 
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'id',
           'terms' => 'PRIVATE_CATEGORY',
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }

}
```

Thats code will hide product from search. But other users still can access the product detail page from direct link.

Here my code that hide the product single pages *(which is not works)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wcpp_hide_product_detail' );
//add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wcpp_hide_product_detail' );

function wcpp_hide_product_detail() {
    if(is_admin()) return;
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if(empty($terms)) return;
    $is_private=false;
    foreach($terms as $term){
        if('PRIVATE_CATEGORY'==$term->term_id){
            $is_private = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(!$is_private) return;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!isset($current_user->roles) || !in_array('PRIVATE_MEMBER', $current_user->roles)){ 
        //need do something here, but not works
        //maybe redirect
        //wp_redirect(home_url());
        /* or like set 404
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        */
    }
}
```

If I set a redirect script, it says: *"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..."*

I think this will works if I can modify the product query to negative ID number which will trigger the *"product not found"* page. But I dont know which is the action hook name to do it. Then I may be my code could works using `wp` action hook like `add_action( 'wp', 'wcpp_hide_product_detail' );`. But I dont know the right hook.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have revisited your code as there was some mistakes *(everything is commented in the code)*. Also:

- You can use [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) to check a user role for the current user.
- You can use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) conditional function to check for post terms of any taxonomy.

The following code will hide products that belongs to a specific product category from user that have not a specific user role. If they try to access that specific products, they will be redirected to shop page with a custom notice…

Additionally the ajax add to cart button or the "Read more" button is replaced on all products loop for that specific products by a disable greyed button *(in front end only)*.

Here is the code:

```
// Hide specific products from shop and archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'wcpp_hide_product' );
function wcpp_hide_product( $q ) {
    // skip for main query and  on admin
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() )
        return;

    // Hide specific products for unlogged users or users without PRIVATE_MEMBER user role
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('PRIVATE_MEMBER') ) {
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'term_id', // it's not 'id' but 'term_id' (or 'name' or 'slug')
           'terms' => 'PRIVATE_CATEGORY',
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}

// Replace add to cart button by a disabled button on specific products in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'wcpp_replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function wcpp_replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    if ( ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('PRIVATE_MEMBER') )
    && has_term( 'PRIVATE_CATEGORY', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {;
        $button = '<a class="button alt disabled">' . __( "Private", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}

// On single product pages, redirect to shop and display a custom notice for specific products
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail' );
function wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail() {
    if ( ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('PRIVATE_MEMBER') )
    && has_term( 'PRIVATE_CATEGORY', 'product_cat' ) && is_product() ) {
        // Add a notice (optional)
        wc_add_notice(__("Sorry, but you are not allowed yet to see this product."), 'notice' );

        // Shop redirection url
        $redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') );
        wp_redirect($redirect_url); // Redirect to shop

        exit(); // Always exit
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme), or in a plugin file.

Tested and works.

Comment: wow, i have a lot of bonus answer. this really great. thank you so much

Comment: for anyone who hard to find the answer. using `template_redirect` hook and change `id` to `term_id` is the answer. the rest is just fixing my bad code